# sql like js library to manipulate arrays

Tags: sql, javascript

I have parsed a csv file into an array of objects. Now I have to issue several alterations on that array. Right now I'm working with lodash' methods, but it's a bit verbose. I would prefer doing it in something like plain old sequel.

Is there any js library that would allow me to issue sql statements against an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Not SQL syntax specifically, but there are some implementations of LINQ (borrowed from C#) implemented in JavaScript. These would essentially help you do what you are asking.

http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/mihaifm/linq